# How can I display an image/plot in a new window and not as background of GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

So I have created a GUI which calls a function when a button is pressed. The function plots an image (centroids on a picture) and is then displayed. However, this image is appearing as the background in my GUI. I want to display the image in a new window.

How do I go about it?

Comment: Alright, thanks Stewie. I was going to add a picture url but I thought the question was pretty self explanatory for regular MATLAB users.

Thanks though. Also, I googled but couldn't find an answer to the question, even on SO. Hence, I posted it. I will delete the question if you believe it won't be of future help

Comment: You're as good a judge as I am when it comes to this. If you have searched for this and didn't find any answer, then you should probably keep it here. My point was that it might benefit from being explained a bit more, especially the answer. A screenshot of where you find the "Next Plot" / "New" option would be nice. Not a necessity though, just a suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by changing "Next Plot" to "New" in the Property Inspector of GUI background.